# what does $ sign do in the following code?

Tags: html, content-management-system

I am working on a CMS (dotcms), and I wanted to edit some bulletpoints when I saw this as part of the code that displays bullet graphics:

```
<img src="$!{hostimg}/Images/c.png"/>
```

I would like to know the part `$!{hostimg}` does. I do not see such a folder on the root of the site or elsewhere in the site.

Comment: It has no meaning in HTML. It probably has something to do with your CMS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the functionality of an unspecified CMS.

Comment: the name of this cms is :dotcms

Comment: it is a variable, look here: $!{lastName} is a variable defined in the structure. http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/MakingYourFirstAdvancedTemplate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a placeholder for a templating engine. The dollar sign in this instance has nothing to do with jQuery.

Templating engines process markup and replace psuedo-variables or placeholders with text stored in variables,

Comment: I agree with this.  up-voting.  :)